# How to deploy a React web app to the Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: reactjs, sapui5, sap-fiori, s4hana, sap-bsp

I have a React web application which I created with the `ui5-webcomponents-react` library from SAP https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents-react.
I wish to make this application available via the SAP Fiori Launchpad (as a tile).

How can I make this happen?

I've successfully uploaded the 'built' app (contents of the `build` folder) to SAP via the method outlined here:
https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/27/how-to-run-reactjs-web-apps-in-sap/ 

(Essentially created a bespoke `Z` BSP application in SE80 and manually uploaded & linked all of the relevant 'minified' files)

And I can access the application via the open web service in SAP.

But I'm unsure how to continue?

Is the above method even the right thing to do? There has to be a much easier way of doing this?

I'm on the latest version of S/4 HANA and don't wish to use Eclipse or the WebIDE (primarily because I'm on the on-premise version and because I'm not a huge fan of the Eclipse IDE as it's considerably slower and more resource heavy compared with VSCode).

Comment: Here is a working repository that I managed to deploy to my Trial BusinessTechnologyPlatform-CloudFoundry: https://github.com/SAP-samples/multi-cloud-html5-apps-samples/tree/main/standalone-approuter-html5-mta-ui5webcomponents  Then like @Immanuel mentions, add it as a URL App in the Launchpad configurator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% this is what you were looking for, but you can add your app as a URL App in the Portal. This will create a tile for the specific app your linking it to.

This might help, Marius Obert wrote a great article on how to add a React app to your LP.
https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/03/cloudfoundryfun-11-integrate-a-react-app-in-the-fiori-launchpad/